# SQL query for fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables

structure of those tables are as the following.

**table one**

```
x    y

2    37
5    37
10   37
12   37
15   37
```

**table two**

```
x      z

2     102
2     105
5     110
10    112
10    115
12    118
12    121
15    127  
15    129
5     131
```

**Required output**

```
y     z

37   102
37   105
37   110
37   112
37   115
37   118
37   121
37   127
37   129
37   131
```

SQL query to do this?

Comment: SQL query you've tried? ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on the `x` column:

```
SELECT y, z
FROM   one
JOIN   two ON one.x = two.x
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a simple `join`.

```
select table_one.y,table_two.z from table_one on table_two on table_one.x = table_two.x
```